# Get the value through looping in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

```
for($i=0;$i<5;i++)
{
    <h2><a href="" class="question_title"><?php echo $value['asked_title'];?> </a></h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" id="question_id" class="question_id" >
}
```

Jquery :

```
$('.question_title').click(function () {
    var value = $('#question_id').val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Friends in this code question_id will be carrying different values for the looping . Here I have writtern code to get the value according to the LOOPING on click of ahref class I would like to fetch the value of hidden value for example in the first iteration title is cow on click ahref it should alert 0 (question_id value). on click on 2nd title cat it should get alert 1 like on clicking 5 different title it should display 0-4 respectively but now onclick on different title it alerts only 0 not the other values . could any one suggest me how to achieve it .

Comment: The `id` should be unique in same socument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 'id' is unique value, it will get only the first element.

Try this:

```
for($i=0;$i<5;i++)
{
<h2><a href="" class="question_title" id="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $value['asked_title'];?> </a></h2>
}
```

Jquery :

```
$('.question_title').click(function()
  {
  alert(event.target.id);
  });
```

Comment: You can use simply `this.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Get the parent `h2` and then next `.question_id` like following.

```js
$('.question_title').click(function() {
   var value = $(this).parent().next('.question_id').val();
   alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2><a href="" class="question_title">Title 0</a></h2>
<input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="0" id="question_id" class="question_id">

<h2><a href="" class="question_title">Title 1</a></h2>
<input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="1" id="question_id" class="question_id">
```

BTW you are using same id `question_id` for multiple elements.

Comment: It reutrns Undefined

Comment: It is working for me. See update. @NavaneethaKrishnanK

Answer (score 0):

For

```
<?php 
for($i=0;$i<5;i++)
{
?>
<h2><a href="#" class="question_title" data-tell="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $value['asked_title'];?> </a></h2>
<input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" id="question_id" class="question_id" >
 <?php  } ?>
```

And in script  use

```
$('.question_title').click(function() {
   alert($(this).attr("data-tell"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having the same id `question_id` in all five hidden fields.

you can have it like this..

```
for($i=0;$i<5;i++)
{
  echo '<h2><a href="" class="question_title" data-value="'.$i.'">'.$value['asked_title'].'</a></h2>';
}
```

jquery

```
$('.question_title').click(function()
{
  var value = $(this).data('value');
  alert(value);
});
```